# glibc - How the function `__ieee754_sqrt (double x)` works

Tags: c, glibc, sqrt

I am trying to get a good understanding of the software implementation of glibc's [`double sqrt(double x)`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/e_sqrt.c;h=017d30416ca9b92cdc87a6cc840ca30791bba558;hb=c064f6a613844181f411aabb2662384a6aefb69e) function. The code is not very well documented.

Can anyone lead me towards the method that has been used there. I need at least its name so I can look it up and try to project it on the code.

Answer (score 1):

Searching for "9.99999999859990725855365213134618E sqrt" gave me this page:

https://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/119879-sqrt-pow-functions.html

Which says:

> It is a combination of Newton's method with some bit trickery that
>   takes advantage of IEEE floating point representation. And it's not
>   really hard to be cleverer than Newton. The guy was genius, but he
>   lived over 300 years ago.

So Newton's square root method might be a good start.

Comment: "And it's not really hard to be cleverer than Newton."  --> hmmm.

Comment: @chux: genius comes and goes but hubris is forever.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can start here:

https://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.25/math_2w__sqrt__compat_8c_source.html#l00025